# Searching for a way to call a function after ".text()" on jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, text, call, back

Is there any way to have a function triggered after the `$('myitem').text()` is completed when using jQuery? I can't use a callback function because jQuery does not support it for `.text()`.

Comment: What's exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What makes you think that `text()` behaves asynchronously?

Comment: Well.. I 'm trying to create an online source code editor.. And for the time being I have a textarea where on keyup I copy it's contents to a <pre> tag. After that I should call the function snippet() (from "Snippet" jquery plugin) in order to highlight the pre. Well.. what makes me think it behaves async is that i did: alert('a'); $('pre').text('aaa'); and the pre 's contents changed before I closed the alert dialog. Maybe I am wrong but I took that as a sign of async behavior.

Comment: @Paris, I don't see that behavior with Firefox 3.6.13 (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NA923/)). Since `alert()` is supposed to be modal, that looks like a bug to me...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NMMec/2/ check it out. It's my full code.. and it doesn't seem to work for some reason... :/ I really don't lnow why...

Comment: @Paris: You're going to need to describe the expected behavior. As it is, the value of the `textarea` is displayed in the `pre`. I don't know what `.snippet()` should be doing.

Comment: .snippet() highlights the source code inside of the specified selector (this is the "pre" in my example). And as you see, the script runs when the page loads but does not run on keyup.

Comment: I think, this is why a lot of these sites do not have this dynamic highlighting. As you can see here in SO, it takes a while before your code is highlighted. Create a timeout then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be off base here but the reason your changes are not correctly styled is because the plugin is trying to be efficient. It doesn't seem to be designed for continual updating.
To force it to work you need to get the plugin to reinitialise each time. I have removed the class attribute to do that [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/jxu3H/).

Another way to do it which won't be as intensive is to use a timeout (as Marnix) suggested. [Here is an example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/Gut6C/).

Finally you could use a different event altogether like `blur()` (so the formatting is only applied after the area loses focus) or create a 'format' button and assign a click event.

I know it is not **strictly** what you are asking for, but I hope this helps!

*Note: All examples only tested in Chrome.*